# How to map a list of checkboxes options to a model first class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this list of options in my web form:

[image]

And I want to work with model-first. But I'm very noob with MVC and Model-first, so I don't know how to better represent this in my model class.

Should I make one attribuite for each item? Or should I make an array where each position is one option (maybe using `enums`)?

```
public bool[] Comportamento { get; set; }
// or
public Comportamento[] Comportamento { get; set; }
// or
public bool Manso { get; set; }
public bool Arisco { get; set; }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a class `CompartamentoViewModel` that looks like this:

```
public class CompartamentoViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your main view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // List of all objects for the view
    public List<CompartamentoViewModel> Compartamentos { get; set; }

    // List of ints to retrieve selected values
    public List<int> SelectedCompartamentos { get; set; }
}
```

In the view, use the description for the text and the ID for the value. In the post, populate `SelectedCompartamentos` with the list of selected IDs.

Disclaimer: I have no idea how to pluralise "Compartamento."

Comment: Compartamento = Behavior; plural = Compartamentos :p

Comment: In this case you are transforming Comportamento into a Table, right? But i'm not sure if I want that in a different table (yet).

Comment: My example above is how your view models should be structured, which is distinct from your data model. For the data model, I would map an enum to a lookup table as per this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj248772.aspx. No need to make it any more complex than this until you have good reason.